# How to apply a raised cosine filter in python?

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signals

I implemented a raised cosine filter:

```
t=np.r_[-2:2+passo:passo]   #Limiting the response to -4T to 4T
# This can be increased or decreased according to the requirement
p=np.zeros(len(t));
for i in range (0, len(t)):
    if t[i]==0:        
        p[i]= (1-a)+4*a/np.pi;
    elif t[i]==1/(4*a) or t[i]==-1/(4*a):
        p[i]=a/np.sqrt(2)*((1+2/np.pi)*np.sin(np.pi/(4*a))+(1-2/np.pi)*np.cos(np.pi/(4*a)));
    else:
        p[i] = (np.sin(np.pi*t[i]*(1-a))+4*a*t[i]*np.cos(np.pi*t[i]*(1+a)))/(np.pi*t[i]*(1-(4*a*t[i])**2))

    response=(p/np.sqrt(sum(p**2)));   #Normalization to unit energy
    z=np.zeros(len(response)-1);
    new1=np.concatenate((z, EDA));
    new=np.concatenate((new1, z))
    EDA_f=lfilter(new, 10, response, axis=0);
```

but I don't understand how to apply it. I try with lfilter but I have not the same result of the Matlab command:

EDA_f=filter(response, 10, new);

This filter required a vector of zeros (response) and only 1 pole (10). lfilter require 2 vectors.
There are other alternatives?

Comment: it would help if you showed your code.

Comment: code should be in question